# how to plot in matplotlib with repitative values in a column

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have a csv file with 8 columns in it. I want to plot a graph between 2 columns using matplotlib. One of the columns has repetitive values. I want to take the mean of the values from the other column which has same corresponding value in the first column.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you add an example of the csv and which columns you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really specific to matplotlib. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has nice support for this kind of data mangling. Read your csv file into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Then, assuming the column you want to group by is named 'key' and the column whose values you want to take means of is named 'value', you can do:

```
grouped = df.groupby('key').mean()
grouped.plot('value')
```